# Missed enroll new MOK on reboot after NVIDIA driver

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I have a situation here with the VM running Ubuntu 22.04 with passthrough GF106 Nvidia NVIDIA Quadro 2000. Some time ago I installed the driver using CLI:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

(it's an old driver but the latest driver for this GPU)

The secure boot was enabled for this VM so it prompted me to enter the password. I rebooted the VM a couple of weeks later and I chose to continue to boot instead of enrolling Mok. Then I remembered why it prompted me to enroll a new key but...
I tried disabling secure boot and reinstalling drivers with `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-driver-390` still had no success. Drivers won't load.
nvidia-smi:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Suggestions on how to reinstall and make it work are appreciated.